# jquery ui autocomplete in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using the jquery ui autocomplete for my jquery-mobile site. It is working without problems, als long as I open the site directly.
If i navigate to the side with ajax navigation it doesn't work.

Edit testable example:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="main" data-add-back-btn="true class="main"">
<div data-role="content">
<input type="search" name="search" id="search" value="" />
</div>
<script>
$('#main').live('pagecreate',function(event, ui) {
var availableTags = [
        "Testone",
        "Testtwo",
        "Testthree"
    ];
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 2,

});
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Just checked apache acces_log. It only gets called, when I access the page directly. If I navigate to the site and input something, it doesn't get called.

Comment: Yes. I also tested it with a javascript array as source, which I defined in the function. With the same result. So calling search.php could not be the problem.

Comment: Yes it always gets fired. Tested it with a alert message. I get the alert multiple times if i was navigating to the site.

Comment: updated first post with a example.

Comment: it seems like a typo, here the quotation marks is a bit messed up here: `data-add-back-btn="true class="main""`. Also, have you tried to replace `pagecreate` with `pageshow`?

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo, but the problem still exists. I also tried pageshow, without success.

Comment: Found a interesting thing! The site with the autocomplete is my index.html. If I start from another page and navigate to the index.html it is working, also with ajax navigation. If my first page is the inde.html it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a jQM site with autocomplete, and hit a similar issue: the ajax call triggered to populate the autocomplete options wasn't always done by the time the page wanted to fire the autocomplete code itself.

I put this down to the nature of the Javascript being triggered (i.e. it's asynchronous, so you take your chances…).

Now, this is a bit of a hack I know, but adding a wee time-out worked for me (you will need to experiment with the time period). In my app I have something like this after my jQM `$(document).bind("mobileinit"...` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    // Horrible, but necessary
    setTimeout(doAutoComplete, 2500);
  });

  function doAutoComplete(){
    $( "#YOUR_FIELD_ID" ).autocomplete({
    // Your ac code here…
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but doesn't fix the issue for me.